# du command - show file or folder in output?

Tags: du

If I run the command `du -ah | sort -nr` is it possible to make it show which line in the output is a file and which folder? Something like the command `ls -l` shows which is file and folder with `d` and `-` in front.

Comment: I seem not to understand what you try to achieve,  the output show both the disk usage of a folder and of each included file. Is this really what you intended? Maybe the --max-depth=N or -hS options are a start?

Comment: @hasgarion `du` command doesn't colorize it's output and doesn't append leading slash to a directory, so it's difficult to distinguish which one is file and which one is a folder in the output. That's what OP is asking about

Comment: Hi , there. I've posted an answer. I think the last approach with `find` command would be ideal for what you want. Please let me know if that works well for you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is sort of possible, but not without aid of another command. Specifically, here we're using GNU awk ( that's important, so check your awk version )

```
$ du -ah | sort -nr | awk '{usage=$1; $1="";cmd="file "$0;cmd |& getline type;print usage,type ;close(cmd)}'             
24K .: directory
4.0K ./testdir: directory
4.0K ./out.txt: ASCII text
4.0K ./3.txt: ASCII text
4.0K ./2.txt: ASCII text
4.0K ./1.txt: ASCII text
```

Of course this approach is slightly flawed since it seems to fail with filenames that contain spaces (still working on improving it )

As alternative, we can also use `find` command to find all the files and run `file` and `du` commands to do our bidding via `-exec` flag, but that looks slightly  ugly (see the edit history). We could, however, use `find`'s  `-printf` flag to print filetype with `%y` format for much prettier output.

```
$ find -mindepth 1 -printf "%y\t" -exec  du "{}" \;  | sort -rn                                       
f   4   ./out.txt
f   4   ./3.txt
f   4   ./2.txt
f   4   ./1.txt
f   0   ./with space.txt
d   4   ./testdir
```

Obviously here `f` is for regular file and `d` is for directory. See `find`'s manual for more info on flags and filetype letters

Answer (score 6):

As Serg says, `du` can't do this by itself. To process filenames safely, the best way is to separate them with the ASCII nul character (`\0`), and `du` can do *that*. So, using that, along with `sort` and `xargs`' ability to handle null-delimited input:

```
du -0ah |
  sort -zh |
  xargs -0 sh -c 'for i; do s=${i%%[[:space:]]*};f=${i#*[[:space:]]}; echo "$s" "$(ls --color -dF "$f")"; done' _
```

The `-0`, `-z` and `-0` options tell `du`, `sort` and `xargs` to use ASCII nul as the separator.

Then, `s=${i%[[:space:]]*}` to get the start of the line until whitespace (which is the size), and `f=${i#*[[:space:]]}` to get everything else (the filename). Then we get `ls` to print the filename with decoration.

Example:

```
$ du -0ah Screenshots | sort -zh | xargs -0 sh -c 'for i; do s=${i%%[[:space:]]*};f=${i#*[[:space:]]}; echo "$s" "$(ls --color -dF "$f")"; done' _
512 Screenshots/desktop.ini*
264K Screenshots/Screenshot (1).png*
269K Screenshots/
```

Because I used `ls --color`, I also get nice colour output:

[image]

Comment: How about this instead? `du -0ah . | sort -zh | while read -r -d '' size file; do printf '%s %s\n' "$size" "$(ls --color -dF -- "$file")"; done`. You don't really need an extra `xargs` and `sh`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf of course. `while` is underappreciated.  I just default to `xargs`.